# Stream audio to several clients

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, streaming, audio-streaming

I am making a website using ASP.NET and i have a webservice using WCF.

I need to figure out how i can stream audio(.mp3 files most likely) to several clients, so that all the clients hear the same, at the same time. I know this can be done using sockets, but I need a lot of different streams(which is not so good with sockets as i would need a new port to every stream, as far as know). 
It is a kind of online radio-ish. Several channels, and users can then listen to the one they want.

Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction for something like this?
It does not have to be through WCF, I just need to figure out some way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to get started with this is to just use [SHOUTcast](http://www.shoutcast.com) or [Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/).

They both work very similarly, providing an HTTP or HTTP-like server that streams MP3.

Comment: I don't see how those two are a solution to this problem.. I don't want some third party webpage/company to have any information about channels and music?

Comment: @MFu, What are you talking abiout?  SHOUTcast and Icecast are just servers for hosting streams.  You don't need to publish your stream in the stream directory.

Comment: Hey, can you please help me how to start work with icecast? I also need the same thing.

Comment: @Anvesh I linked to the Icecast site which has a lot of information on how to get started.  I don't know where your stuck.  You should post a new question, probably over on SuperUser.com.